# data structures error : expected expression at line 33

Tags: data-structures

[I am doing this data structure program and it showing a error : expected expression ')' token at line 33. i don't have any idea how to get over this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC6uN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: Please provide your detail code with a proper explain where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for (i=0,i<m+n;)
```

The comma after the `0` should be a semicolon. That line should be:

```
for (i=0;i<m+n)
```

Also, did you really mean to write a `for` loop that has no increment step. It's perfectly legal, but not exactly a common thing to do.